# how to install Android app without need to uninstall previous version?

Tags: java, android

I have developed an Android application. Every time I want to re install app in my device I have to uninstall previous app myself and then install new one. how to solve this problem?

Comment: are You installing a signed apk or from IDE directly?

Comment: installing an apk without first uninstalling the previous version should actually update the existing version

Comment: then there is no other way. If You want to install an unsigned APK over an signed APK, You have to delete the previous version. You should install Your app via IDE and only at the end, install apk for testing...

Comment: I mean I have to uninstall it by myself

Comment: it can not happen because of device take or device get package name and version if you install another version with same package name it will @override on first apk

Comment: at a time 2 apk or same kind of application you can not install in device

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you cannot have multiple versions of the same app on your device (by packageName and signature I mean).

1. If you mean by using ADB, then use:

> adb install -r com.example.app.apk

This will `install` but also remove (`-r`) if necessary before doing so.

2. If you mean manually, then your application will be updated (= uninstalled then re-installed).
3. If your mean by your IDE, your IDE is actually doing what I wrote above.

Comment: Nice answer there mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using the same signing keys on all of your pc's. I suspect that is the cause of your problem.

You would then use it like this in your gradle config, note use your own paths, this is for demo only

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
         .....
    }
    debug {
        storeFile file(String.format("%s/%s/%s", "$rootProject.projectDir", "keys", "debug.keystore"))
        storePassword "android"
        keyAlias "debug"
        keyPassword "android"
    }
}
```

Note, don't install your app from the store, it is signed with a different key, you will get the same error.